# IE8 Shows website in a weird manner

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong and which part of code problematic for IE 8 browser but getting some screen like that:
http://joxi.ru/AKrSUhjKTJAsAdwb1CA

All latest browsers shows it correctly like that:

http://joxi.ru/S6rSUv3JTJAWOJoVDFI

Anyone with good IE experience,why this problem occurs?

Answer (score 2):

IE8 does not support many of the features you are using. In particular, the lack of support for `background-size` is killing your inner circles.

Comment: And what do you suggest?

Comment: Considering IE8 is almost 5 years old and has been replaced by IE9 for the last three years, personally... I wouldn't give a shit about people who deliberately disable Windows Update.

Comment: The problem is customer forcibly wants ie8 support. and only bug on website is this

Comment: Check [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#browsers) on browser support. You may also try to set document mode in IE8 to standard.

Answer (score 0):

Well with a little search I've found this solution for `background-size` in IE6+ :

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
src='images/logo.gif',
sizingMethod='scale');

-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
src='images/logo.gif',
sizingMethod='scale')";
```

source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532969%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

It works with IE 6+

Can't really tell if its going to work in your case, without having any of your code to test it with.